# Is it Possible to Connect Two Tables from Different Servers on MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know if is possible to connect two tables from different Servers on MS SQL Server. If so, how do I do this? If it is not possible on MS SQL Server, is there any RDBMS able to do it?

Comment: Define "connect". SQL Server has [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine) to query data across servers.

Comment: I will read the link, thanks. What I meant by 'Connect' was to be able to query data from two tables from different servers all in one query document. For example: I have a table x on server 'A' and a table y on server 'B'. I would like to divide the column x (On table x Server A) by the column y (On table y Server B).

Comment: Yes, linked servers would make this possible. There are performance caveats to consider when you are transferring many rows from one server to another, though, which linked queries may do in a non-obvious way. Recent versions of SQL Server also offer [PolyBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-guide), which is a sort of "linked servers on steroids" that's primarily intended to link non-SQL Server sources. There's also [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) for moving data constantly.

Comment: What do you mean by a non-obvious way? I didn't get this part.  Is there a top 1 thing I should be careful about when executing this?

Comment: Most prominently, if you do a query on server A that performs `JOIN`s to a table on server B, it isn't always obvious if the optimizer will choose to send rows from A to B, or from B to A, and this choice can matter a lot if one table is much bigger than the other. In extreme cases it can be faster to use the link to explicitly copy the data from the smaller table into a temp table on the server with the larger table. You should also take care that the link is marked "collation compatible" (and that it's true) to avoid the problem of string comparisons having to send over every row.

Comment: Thank you so much. The way I am thinking I will have to JOIN the table from Server B to filter out a specific data on Server A. But this part of the query is inside a temp table. I will create two tables to try it first. Again, thank you so much.